# "Build for archiving" work, "Archive" does not

Tags: ios, xcode, archive, restkit

In my current project I am integrating RestKit library (I don't know if it matters), trying to deliver the app for testing when I use "Archive" the compiler complains

```
 "RestKit/RestKit.h" is not found
```

while building and running the app (even on iPhones, not just the simulator) does not show any problem at all.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. It appears to be a bug or something in how Xcode handles static libraries and implicit dependencies. You can find several suggestions here: [Compile, Build or Archive problems with Xcode 4 (and dependencies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584317/compile-build-or-archive-problems-with-xcode-4-and-dependancies)

For me, step 3 on the answer was the solution. Also see step 8 on the answer here: [How do you get implicit dependencies to work with workspaces in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534235/how-do-you-get-implicit-dependencies-to-work-with-workspaces-in-xcode-4/8116994#8116994)

Answer (score 1):

RestKit installation into your XCode 4 project should be uneventful (at least it was for me). However finding the proper up-to-date documentation on how to do it the right way wasn't exactly easy to find.

Check that you followed steps steps as described in these screenshots: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/tree/master/Docs/Images/Installation