# How to create workspace with multiple projects to connect in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios6, workspace, xcode4.5

I want to connect two projects. I have no idea about creating workspace and connect the multiple projects in xcode. How can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following links , Hope you get the solution :)

[How should I manage dependencies across projects in an Xcode workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483909/how-should-i-manage-dependencies-across-projects-in-an-xcode-workspace)

[How do you get implicit dependencies to work with workspaces in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534235/how-do-you-get-implicit-dependencies-to-work-with-workspaces-in-xcode-4?lq=1)

[What's the correct way to configure XCode 4 workspaces to build dependencies when needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427396/whats-the-correct-way-to-configure-xcode-4-workspaces-to-build-dependencies-whe?lq=1)