# Build static library Target with main Target for proper architecture in XCode?

Tags: xcode, architecture, project, static-libraries, target

I am currently developing an iPhone app in XCode that requires a static library that is built from another XCode project I have made. I currently have both targets in the same project, and I need the static library project to build and run for the proper architecture when I build the project that uses it.

As of now I have to open the static library project on its own, build it from there, find where it was built, and then remove the old library and add the new one to my project that uses it.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution lies within the idea of [workspaces](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html). [This s.o. thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427396/whats-the-correct-way-to-configure-xcode-4-workspaces-to-build-dependencies-whe) might also be helpful. I think the general layout youll want to create is a new workspace where you will add both projects, the client and the library, that way they are both within reach.

Best of luck!